# Export loader Geometry from three js to JSON

Tags: json, ionic-framework, 3d, three.js, geometry

How do I export the loaded geometry to x,y and z axis vertices in JSON?

```
var json = geometry.toJSON();
```

The above code simply prints out all the vertices but not able to identify which of its is x,y or z axis vertices for which object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what type of geometry you have.

With [THREE.Geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry), `geometry.vertices` is an array of Vertex objects with `.x`, `.y`, and `.z` properties.

With [THREE.BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry), `geometry.attributes.position` is a BufferAttribute instance:

```
var position = geometry.attributes.position;
var json = {position: []};
for (var i = 0; i < position.count; i++) {
  json.position.push({
    x: position.getX( i ),
    y: position.getY( i ),
    z: position.getZ( i )
  });
}
console.log( JSON.stringify( json, null, 2 ) );
```

If you access `position.array`, it is a flattened array of the form `[x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ... ]`.

Comment: Is there any way to convert the positions to a json format how I get in the X,Y and Z axis?

Comment: Could you specify in your question how you want the JSON to look? It’s not clear what you want here..

Comment: Sample JSON Format

{
   "nodes":[
      {
         "name":0,
         "x":531,
         "y":312,
         "z":200,
      },
      {
         "name":1,
         "x":631,
         "y":323,
         "z":200,
      }
   ],
   "paths":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "from":0,
         "to":1
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "from":0,
         "to":55
      }
   ]
}

Comment: Added some sample code that pushes all vertices into a JS array. I'm not sure what you mean by "nodes" or "paths". You may want to read about indexed and non-indexed geometry, and how mesh data is represented.

Comment: Thanks Don McCurdy , I will look it out. The coding is based on navigation algorithm. In that algorithm i need to pass the data in that format. Nodes represent each building name and paths represent the connection between the buildings